# Bitwise AND operations in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-and

I make a project that reads value from a remote JSON. In this project the remote JSON can give me with one variable 16 different types of alarm. The implementation is by a bynary 16bit value expressed in int. So if there is the third alarm it should return me 8 (bynary 1000) and if the second,eigth and tenth alarm is up it return me 1284 (binary 10100000100). Well when there is no alarm it returns me 0.
So, I create a function in JS (accordly to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)) that passing the value returned (8/1284/0 in the example) returns me a simple true or false if there is an alarm. The function is pretty simple:

```
function IsOnAlarm(passedVal) {
    if (passedVal & 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

but it does not function :-(
I create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KQH43/2/) that shows the problem. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you dont want to know the specific values return passedVal!=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as far as I understand you just need to check whether the value is 0. There's no need for any bitwise operation.

```
function IsOnAlarm(passedVal) {
    return passedVal != 0;
}
```

Side note: `passedVal & 0` is always `0` no matter what `passedVal` is (that's why it always goes to `else`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like

```
function IsOnAlarm(passedVal) {
    if (passedVal != 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/KQH43/3/

Answer (score 0):

The AND operator always return false if one of the operands is zero, see below:

```
0 & 0 = 0
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

The easiest way to rewrite your function is as follows:

```
function IsOnAlarm(passedVal) {
    return !!passedVal;
}
```

Explanation: the double negation operation (`!!`) allows you to cast the input to boolean. Any non-zero value will evaluate to true, zero evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pqpK/), it is using bitwise AND comparison.

I've modified your function to make it easier to understand:

```
function AreAlarmsOn(alarmsToCheck, alarmState) {
    return and(alarmsToCheck, alarmState)!=0;
}
```

It takes alarmsToCheck and checks its bits against alarmState bits, alarmsToCheck can have bits for several alarms if you need to check multiple alarms.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var getFlags = function(val) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        results.push(!!((val >> i) & 1));
    }
    return results;
};

var flags = getFlags(1284);

flags[2] //=> true
flags[8] //=> true
flags[10] //=> true
// all other values ==> false / undefined
```